# What is the algorithm for computing quantiles?

Tags: matlab, descriptive-statistics, quantiles, qq-plot

According to the Matlab documentation for `qqplot`, the `ith` ordered value is plotted against the `(1-0.5)/N th` quantile of the specified distribution.  I tried to see what values are computed from the `qqplot` function using the code:

```
% Sample data
data = [20.1356902600000,22.9968989300000,27.8533897000000,34.6339252300000,35.9040685800000,37.1956327500000,37.7866312200000,51.8297694800000,54.4870463000000,55.9331364700000,55.9442022600000,57.8593133700000,58.4149264500000,60.2702913000000,63.4486306400000,63.4486306400000,72.1816635900000,72.1816635900000,72.6987322200000,74.3357331500000,75.9363293000000,75.9363293000000,75.9363293000000,75.9363293000000,75.9363293000000,75.9363293000000,77.5225121300000,77.6878835100000,78.2241174600000,78.7961655500000,79.1008427300000,79.4293391500000,80.2392159200000,80.4032394000000,80.5065995800000,80.5608526300000,81.6286695600000,83.1438511500000,83.2355410900000,83.4033539900000,83.4291352300000,83.9948416400000,84.3049374900000,84.7920938400000,85.2741586700000,85.4844301700000,87.5935000200000,87.6738399200000,88.2772000900000,89.3328328700000,89.8733762200000,90,90,90,91.2300629900000,93.0954777400000,94.5155698300000,95.2079061600000,95.9303831900000,96.7973475600000,97.1230107200000,97.6290536100000,98.5358378400000,99.7607840800000,100.282401200000,100.853007300000,104.063670700000,104.877246400000,104.952311800000,105.664266900000,111.584437700000,112.086132400000,114.605495500000,114.888200000000,114.888200000000,115.241718100000,116.993923400000,120.813417400000,123.484955000000,123.998002500000,137.948493100000,142.466756700000,145.424388300000,146.713218300000,149.316582900000,149.762000400000,157.720284500000,163.781591600000,179.372353000000];

% QQPlot
H = qqplot(data); set(H, 'Visible', 'off'); title(' '); xlabel(''); ylabel('')
%Click on the axes that contains the child(ren) you are interested in. 
kids = get(gca,'Children');
%Extract X and Y Data by indexing into kids
xdata = get(kids,'XData');
ydata = get(kids,'YData');
xdata1 = xdata{1};  %empirical quantile for blue line 
ydata1 = ydata{1};  %sorted input data for blue line
xdata2 = xdata{3};  %theoritical (std. normal) quantile for red line 
ydata2 = ydata{3};  %empirical data for red dashed line

% Plot the data
plot(xdata1, ydata1, '.b', 'Linewidth', 2)
hold on;
plot(xdata2, ydata2, '-.r', 'Linewidth', 2)
ylabel('Quantiles of input samples', 'fontsize',8)
xlabel('standard normal quantiles', 'fontsize',8)
```

I am perplexed as to how the `xdata1` and `xdata2` values were obtained. For instance, the median of the distribution (or the `0.5 quantile`) is the `(n+1)/2` `= 45th` observation, which corresponds to `ydata1` value of `85.2742`. Similarly, the `75th` `percentile` (or the `0.75 quantile`) is the `67.5th` observation – which corresponds to `ydata1` value of `104.2671`. How then did the `qqplot` function compute the corresponding `xdata1` values of `0` and `0.6835` for the `0.5` and `0.75 quantiles`?

Also, is there any appropriate reference material/publication where i can find the description of this algorithm?

Comment: Not sure about Matlab, but R has good documentation for its sample quantile functions (under ?quantile). Matlab could use similar.

Comment: Thanks @jwimberley. I don't use nor know much about R. Can you please post me the link?

Comment: No link (docs in code). R references a paper by Hyndman and Fan (1996) that presents 9 sample quantile algorithms; it's likely that Matlab uses one of these.

Comment: Ok. I would have a look at it. Thank you very much

Comment: Unless one actually runs the Matlab code, there is no way to determine what the problem is!  All you say is "this seems not to be the case."  If you could be more specific about the output and why it is not what you expected, then this question might be answerable.

Comment: Thank you @Whuber. I have just thrown a bit more light as to why i am inundated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the documentation for `qqplot` explains that these are the quantiles of the standard Normal distribution.

Comment: The documentation only gives the formula stated above, which just basically computes the quantiles from any given position. From my exploration with other dataset i noticed that the `xdata1` values for the `median` are always = 0, while the values below and above the `median`  are mirrored `-ve and +ve` numbers, respectively. My thoughts on this is that Matlab somehow uses an algorithm to scale the distribution to a linear form?... just maybe!.

Comment: Now i know what it is. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245396/how-to-read-the-x-axis-of-this-qqplot?rq=1